Wahoo "app is blocked" connecting to Google Fit
I have an aging Samsung Galaxy S7 (Android 8) with the Wahoo Elemnt app installed and connected to Google Fit.
I am migrating to a new Pixel 8 with GrapheneOS (Android 15). When I install the Elemnt app on it and attempt to connect it to Google Fit, I get:

This app is blocked
This app tried to access sensitive info in your Google Account [...]

I found a Reddit post that indicates it is not specific to GrapheneOS but I would expect more search hits if the problem were widespread.
Has anyone successfully linked the Wahoo app with Google Fit recently?

The error message you are getting is generated:

If the app or site doesn’t meet Google's security standards, Google might block you from signing into your account via it by default. Less secure apps can make it easier for hackers to get in to your account, so blocking sign-ins from these apps helps keep your account safe.
You can try turning this off if you understand the risk:
https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps

From Google Support

Sadly: "This setting is not available for your account." If this is the issue, it's odd the S7 could still connect.

"You can sign in to your Google Account from any third-party app that has the "Sign in with Google" option. In some cases you may need to remove your Google Account and then add it again on your device." The app does seem to use that for login but not sure I want to risk trying to delete my accounts from my phone.

"Doesn't meet security standards" can mean it was written for an old version of Google's API, which is why it would work on an old phone but not a new one. I assume you're getting the wahoo app by searching play store and not some harder method, so it should be up to date, but sounds like maybe it isn't.

@ChrisH yes, latest version from google play. looking at the most recent reviews, I see a couple of other people echoing that syncing to google fit fails. so seems it's not just me

The latest version in Google Play was uploaded in July, that was the last moment they would accept apps targeting Android 13. This points to the direction that they're using some API that was declared dangerous at Android 14 or 15.
